# How to send transaction from metamask to another metamask account using smart contract method

Tags: web3js, metamask, javascript, ganache

I have two accounts in metamask imported from ganache and well conected , when I called the function buy, web3 always used my default account in the metamask, I want to send transaction from my account one to account two
using methode of the smart contract this is how i call my metamask account

```
   getMetaskAccountID: function () {
    web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);

    // Retrieving accounts
    web3.eth.getAccounts(function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error:', err);
            return;
        }
        console.log('getMetaskID:', res);
        App.metamaskAccountID = res[0];
     

    })
},
```

when i tried to change account and called my smart contract function i got an Internal JSON-RPC error . and this is how i called my function

```
 buyItem: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var processId = parseInt($(event.target).data('id'));
    App.contracts.SupplyChain.deployed().then(function (instance) {
        const walletValue = web3.utils.toWei("1", "ether");
        return instance.buyItem(App.upc,{ from: App.metamaskAccountID, value: walletValue });
    }).then(function (result) {
        $("#ftc-item").text(result);
        console.log('buyItem', result);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    });
},
```

And I want to know if i can chose the account address of my smart contract.

Comment: Hello @Rami fahd, welcome to Ethereum SE. I'm not sure to correctly understand your question, your issue is that you can't call your `buy` method from two different Metamask accounts ?

Comment: @clement my issue is when i deployed my contract it used the first account of my ganache when i do buy  function from the first account it but from herself  , then when i try to change the account and click on a function it shows me an erreur internal json rpc , i want do a buy function to send eth from my default account to the second account of metamask using my local network

Comment: @Ramifahd What's the exact error message? What does buy function do? Are the buy parameters correct? ie not undefined.